# Krishna visiting Sudra's home or touching a Sudra

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, krishna, varna

In Mahabharata, Pandavas used to visit Sudra's homes. It can be clarified from the following passage

> Vaisampayana said, 'Then all the citizens (of Varanavata) on hearing
> that the son of Pandu had come, were filled with joy at the tidings,
> speedily came out of Varanavata, in vehicles of various kinds
> numbering by thousands, taking with them every auspicious article as
> directed by the Sastras, for receiving those foremost of men. And the
> people of Varanavata, approaching the sons of Kunti blessed them by
> uttering the Jaya and stood surrounding them. That tiger among men,
> viz., the virtuous Yudhishthira thus surrounded by them looked
> resplendent like him having the thunderbolt in his hands (viz., Indra)
> in the midst of the celestials. And those sinless ones, welcomed by
> the citizens and welcoming the citizens in return, then entered the
> populous town of Varanavata decked with every ornament. Entering the
> town those heroes first went, O monarch, to the abodes of Brahmanas
> engaged in their proper duties. Those foremost of men then went to the
> abodes of the officials of the town, and then of the Sutas and the
> Vaisyas and **then to those of even the Sudras**, O bull of Bharata's
> race, thus adored by the citizens, the Pandavas at last went with
> Purochana going before them, to the palace that had been built for
> them, Purochana then began to place before them food and drink and
> beds and carpets, all of the first and most agreeable order. The
> Pandavas attired in costly robes, continued to live there, adored by
> Purochana and the people having their homes in Varanavata.
>
> [[Section 148, Jatugriha Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01149.htm)

Are there any such instances where Krishna visited Sudra's home or touching a Sudra?

Comment: From [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16449/4732) you can get those verses where Vidura himself is saying that he is a Sudra by birth "Vidura said, 'I am born in the Sudra order and, therefore, do not venture to say more than what I have already said." So, the answer given here is correct.

Comment: Krishna was brought up in nanda gavon which is sudra only he lived played and acted like one this shows how much krisnas is affectionate to sutras and girls its for them he concised vedas and upanishad into bhagvad gita previously inaccessible to sudra

Comment: Prasanna, the Yadavas were Kshatriya not Sudra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Mahabharat era - Mahatma Vidura [महात्मा विदुर] - who was a dasi-putra (son of servant of Hastinapur's king) - was considered as Shudra (means worker class) Varna. And Sri Krishna did visit his home - when he visited as a "messenger of Pandavas" - with the purpose to avoid the war.

Answer (score 8):

See we need to understand that Bhagavan doesn't differentiate anyone based on Birth/Class. Lord Krishna(Vishnu/Rama) hugged Kubja(Nishada) and even visited her house.He embraced Guha and accepted love of Sabari. He also married Jambavati(Nishada).He ate banana peels offered by Sudra Vidura's wife and prefers to live in his small house than royal Kingdom of Duryodhana. He also blessed the Fruit Seller. Lord doesnt see birth as consideration to reciprocate love.

> The almighty Lord **greeted everyone present by bowing His head,
> exchanging greetings, embracing, shaking hands, looking and smiling,
> giving assurances and awarding benedictions, even to the lowest
> dogeaters in rank**.(SB 1.11.22)
>
> Unlike an ordinary living entity, my Lord, You do not discriminate
> between friends and enemies, the favorable and the unfavorable,
> **because for You there is no conception of higher and lower**. **Nonetheless, You offer Your benedictions according to the level of one’s service, exactly as a desire tree delivers fruits according to
> one’s desires and makes no distinction between the lower and the
> higher**.(SB 7.9.27)
>
> The pure devotee is always within the core of My heart, and I am
> always in the heart of the pure devotee. My devotees do not know
> anything else but Me, and I do not know anyone else but them.(SB
> 9.4.68)
>
> Sri Krsna who is very affectionate toward His devotees, **sells Himself to a devotee who offers Him merely a Tulasi leaf and a palmful of water**. The Lord liquidates the debt by offering Himself to the devotee.” (CC Adi 3.104–107)

In recent times,Lord Krishna baked Pots and sold them for Gora Khumbhar. He drove cattle and ate with Chokmela Ji. He carried Cow Dung with Janabai and helped her in washing the utensils and sweeping the floor.He came as Pariah Massager to protect Damaji and washes feet of a King when his Barber Bhakta Sena Nahvi was sick!He blessed Outcastes like Thirupan Alvar and Kanaka Dasa with ever lasting fame. That's why its said that

> Birth in a low family is no disqualification for the execution of devotional
> service. And birth in a family of brahmanas is no qualification. Anyone who
> takes to devotional service is exalted, whereas a non devotee is always condemned and abominable. In the **discharge of devotional service to the Lord,
> there is no consideration of the status of one's family**. (CC Antya 4.66,67)
>
> **It is through deep love that the Chandala makes me his own, while
> without it the Brahmin is nothing to me**.” (Garuda Purana 1.231.9)
>
> A brahmana who is expert in studying all four Vedas is not dear to Me, but
> a devotee who comes from a family of outcastes (candalas) is dear to Me. **Whatever he touches becomes pure. That devotee, although born in a family of
> outcastes is as worshipable as I am**. (Hari-bhakti-vilasa 10.91)
>
> A Bramhana who is expert in studying all four Vedas is not dear to Me.
> **But a devotee who comes from a family of Chandalas is dear to Me. He
> should be offered gifts and one should accept gifts from him. He is as
> worshipable as I am**. (Hari-Bhakta-Vilasa 10.127)

Answer (score 1):

Krishna goes to Vidura's home.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05091.htm

> The food supplied by Vidura alone, should, I think, be eaten by me.'

Other people also came.

> Having said this unto Duryodhana who was ever incapable of bearing anything against his own wishes, Kesava of mighty arms then came out of that blazing palace of Dhritarashtra's son. And the high-souled Vasudeva of mighty arms, coming out of that mansion, directed his steps towards the abode of the illustrious Vidura. And while that mighty-armed one staying within Vidura's abode, thither came unto him Drona, and Kripa, and Bhishma, and Vahlika, and many of the Kauravas. And the Kauravas that came there addressed Madhava, the heroic slayer of Madhu, saying, 'O thou of Vrishni's race, we place at thy disposal our houses with all the wealth within them.'

But Krishna refused them.

'The slayer of Madhu, of mighty energy, answered them saying, 'Ye may go away. I am much honoured by these your offers.'

Krishna was entertained and gratified by Vidura.

> And after all the Kurus had gone away, Vidura, with great care entertained that unvanquished hero of Dasarha's race with every object of desire. And Kunti then placed before the illustrious Kesava clean and savoury food in abundance. Therewith the slayer of Madhu first gratified the Brahmanas. Indeed, from that food he first gave a portion, along with much wealth, unto a number of Brahmanas conversant with the Vedas, and then with his attendants, like Vasava in the midst of the Marutas, he dined on what remained of the clean and savoury food supplied by Vidura.'"

Krishna also explained why he cannpt expect Duryodhana's offers.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05091.htm

> "Vaisampayana continued, 'Thus addressed by the king, Janardana of Dasarha's race, casting his eyes on Dhritarashtra's son and ah his counsellors, replied, saying, 'Not from desire, nor from wrath, nor from malice, nor for gain, nor for the sake of argument, nor from temptation, would I abandon virtue. One taketh another's food when one is in distress. At present, however, O king, thou hast not inspired love in me by any act of thine, nor have I myself been plunged into distress. Without any reason, O king, thou hatest, from the moment of their birth, thy dear and gentle brothers,--the Pandavas--endued with every virtue. This unreasonable hatred of thine for the sons of Pritha ill becometh thee. The sons of Pandu are all devoted to virtue. Who, indeed, can do them the least injury? He that hateth them, hateth me; he that loveth them, loveth me. Know that the virtuous Pandavas and my own self have but a common soul. He, who, following the impulses of lust and wrath, and from darkness of soul, hateth and seeketh to injure one that is possessed of every good quality, is regarded as the vilest of men. That wrathful wretch of every good quality, is regarded as the vilest of men. That wrathful wretch of uncontrolled soul, who, from ignorance and avarice hateth his kinsmen endued with every auspicious quality, can never enjoy his prosperity long. He, on the other hand, who, by good offices, winneth over persons endued with good qualities, even if he beareth aversion of them within his heart, enjoyeth prosperity and fame for ever and ever. Defiled by wickedness, all this food, therefore, deserveth not to be eaten by me.